# How to cast ReadableStream to Readable

Tags: javascript, node.js

The internal library which I'm using is providing `NodeJS.ReadableStream`, which I need to pass to `nodemailer` (attachments), which is taking as parameter `Readable`.

```
 Argument of type 'Buffer | ReadableStream' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Buffer | Readable'.
  Type 'ReadableStream' is not assignable to type 'Buffer | Readable'.
```

---

Resolved. Created `Readable` instance, and used `.wrap` method for `ReadableStream`

Comment: Thank you very much for sharing! Link to node doc: https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_wrap_stream

Answer (score 3):

Posting the solution provided from [@hejkerooo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8153143/hejkerooo) as an answer:

```
const { OldReader } = require('./old-api-module.js'); 
const { Readable } = require('node:stream');
const oreader = new OldReader(); // ReadableStream
const myReader = new Readable().wrap(oreader); // Readable
```

Source: https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#readablewrapstream